# Segue from a Custom Cell in UItableVew in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, swift2

I have created a custom cell and want to perform a segue to another ViewController by clicking on it.

I used `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and performed a segue but no result. The segue does not work!

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetailViewSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let cellname = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! CardTableViewCell;
    let DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
    DetailViewController.title = cellname.textLabel?.text 
}
```

Comment: yep! I'm not able to go to the other controller

Comment: But you are sure that the code in the didSelctRowAtIndexPath is called?

Comment: I checked . I put a print() in the didSelectAtRowIndex method. It is not being called! What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following items:

**First**, make sure that you established your segue. In your table view controller, control click on the yellow icon at the top of the table view controller's scene in the storyboard. Drag it to your destination view.

**Second**, make sure that the name of your **Storyboard Segue** matches the desired value (`toDetailViewSegue`).

- In your storyboard, click on the segue that you created (either in the **Document Outline** or directly on the storyboard).
- In the Utilities bar (right-side pane), go to the **Attributes Inspector**. There you will see `Identifier` of the Storyboard Segue. Make sure that it is the correct value.

[image]

**Third**, make sure that your custom table view cell has **User Interaction Enabled** checked.

- In your storyboard, click on your custom cell.
- Go to the **Attributes Inspector**. Look for the **Interaction** field within the **View** section. Make sure that it is checked.

[image]

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal Hmm. Do you have your code anywhere (i.e., on Github)?

Comment: ..I'm getting the following warning..Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal If you are getting the "unreachable" error then you have scene (view controller) in your storyboard that is not connected to anything. Is the scene that is unreachable your destination view controller, the one that is called from your custom cell segue?

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal The "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" issue sounds like what is says... you are missing an identifier, a name to your scene so that it doesn't know where to go. Are you sure you did the "**First**" step I mentioned in my post?

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal Sure. Make it public.

Comment: Yes, I did have a view controller which was unreachable but it wasn't either of the two.

Comment: here's the public link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4x57CYef4-mOFBKZWUxZElfeHM

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal Looks ok. But, does the storyboard scene for your detail view controller indicate that it has a custom class of `DetailViewController`? (Select the detail vc scene, go to the right pane and click on the **IdentityInspector** and look at the **Custom Class** value. It should say DetailViewController.

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal ???? *Something* is not right. Lol! Make sure there are **no** typos. Also, you can look at the source code of the storyboard (open as source code) and try to make sure all that the connections are misplaced. (This might not be intuitive and might be more confusing than helpful.)

Comment: Ok no probs i'll give it a try ! Thnx for all the help! :)

Comment: @UttkarshAgrawal In the source code of the storyboard, within the xml of your *source* vc scene look for **objects -> tableViewController -> connections -> segue**. It will have a `destination` value (something like `RB8-Ec-qIq`).  Make sure that value **matches** the `id` value in your *detail* vc scene **objects -> viewController**. Good luck!! :)

Comment: yep it does match !! have a look at the screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4x57CYef4-mOFBKZWUxZElfeHM